# Create a view in Share Point which contains List items from 2 lists

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to create a view in share point so that it shows list items from 2 different lists? 
For example I have a list 'Meeting' and another ‘Task’ under a subsite. I want to show all the list items from these lists in one calendar view so user can see Meeting and task in one view in the subsite.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Calendar Overlay** feature to achieve this.

[Aggregate SharePoint Event/Items into your Calendar view using Calendar Overlay](http://weblogs.asp.net/sharadkumar/archive/2010/03/12/aggregate-sharepoint-event-items-into-your-calendar-view-using-calendar-overlay.aspx)

[image: CalendarOverlay - taken from linked article]